# BibTeX does not read a reference from the .bib file

Tags: bibtex

I use a toolchain that uses `pdflatex` and `bibtex`, with .tex files generated from Isabelle theory sources.

I did typeset my first two references correctly but I cannot typeset a third reference. The reference appears in the bibliography but its number does not appear as a citation in the text, a question mark appears.

My build script is

```
pdflatex root.tex
bibtex root
pdflatex root.tex
pdflatex root.tex
```

I tried to move the bibliography entry in the .bib file from the end to the beginning, to no avail. I also tried to give another entry in the bib file, that also did not work.

BibTeX does not report any warning or error, so the syntax of my .bib file seems to be correct.

`pdflatex` says

```
LaTeX Warning: Citation `Appel-VST' on page 1 undefined on input line 65.
```

It does have an entry in the .bib file.

What could cause this and how can I fix this?

Comment: Please provide a MWE.

Comment: If you don't cite the reference, it won't appear.  Add `\nocite(Appel-VST}` to give it a phantom citation.

Answer (score 0):

It would have been hard to create a minimal working example as it requires installing Isabelle.

It turned out that in my `document/root.tex` I referred to my .bib file as

```
\bibliography{../../MyBib}
```

as my bibliography file resides in a root directory for all of my papers, but the logic of the Isabelle document preparation toolchain requires it to be in the current build directory:

```
\bibliography{MyBib}
```

The toolchain copies my .bib file into the build directory. The way I should refer to the grandparent directory is in the `ROOT` file:

```
document_files ( in "../.." )
  "MyBib.bib"
```

this specifies what to copy to the build directory.

And now it works.